# How to get component Object?

Tags: extjs

I have a view like:

```
Ext.define('Demo.example.OpenRequest', {
    extend: 'Ext.draw.Component',
    xtype: 'demo',
    height: 280,
    width: 1213,
    viewBox: false,
    listeners: {
        'beforerender': function (panel) {
            alert("Hi");
            alert(panel.param);
            alert(panel);
            var itemArray = panel.items;
            itemArray.forEach(function (i) {
                if (i.itemId == 'green-rect') {
                    i.addCls('x-hide-display');
                }
            });
        }
    },
    constructor: function (config) {
        this.items = [{
                type: "image",
                src: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/double-j-design/origami-colored-pencil/64/green-user-icon.png',
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                translate: {
                    x: 10,
                    y: 80
                }
            },
            {
                type: 'rect',
                itemId: 'green-rect',
                width: 200,
                height: 50,
                radius: 10,
                fill: 'green',
                opacity: 0.5,
                stroke: 'black',
                'stroke-width': 2,
                translate: {
                    x: 400,
                    y: 110
                },
                listeners: {
                    click: function (as) {
                        alert('A');
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                type: 'rect',
                width: 200,
                height: 50,
                radius: 10,
                itemId: 'red1-rect',
                fill: 'red',
                opacity: 0.5,
                stroke: 'black',
                'stroke-width': 2,
                translate: {
                    x: 890,
                    y: 10
                },
                listeners: {
                    click: function () {
                        alert('B');
                    }
                }
            }];

        if (this.items) {
            Ext.apply(config, {
                items: this.items
            });
        }
        this.callParent([config]);
    }
});
```

In beforerender listener I want to hide the green rectangle based on value. I am checking there if i.itemId == 'green-rec' I am adding a class that has hidden property.But I it is giving error as undefined function.
How should I hide it.

css:

```
.x-hide-display {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ema) and when you want the real items to iterrate over you need `panel.items.items`.
The following code should work

```
var itemArray = panel.items.items; //now you have the items you want to iterrate over
Ext.Object.each(itemArray, function (key, value) {
    if (value.itemId == 'green-rect') {
        value.addCls('x-hide-display');
    }
});
```

---

The type of panel.items is [Ext.util.Collection](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Collection-method-each) so you can just do the following

```
var itemArray = panel.items;
itemArray.each(function (item) {
    if (item.itemId == 'green-rect') {
        item.addCls('x-hide-display');
    }
});
```

Comment: I did that its not working .Error: undefined is not a function. I wanted to check the type alert(i instanceof Ext.data.sprite.Rect) It is telling rec is not defined.

Comment: Is `i` an object of `Ext.draw.sprite.Rect` ?

Comment: Any other way to check object type?

Comment: After using the modified code It gives error as Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ( I think this error occurs when addCls() comes to picture)

Comment: I think It is not entering to the .each(function(){} as alert used in between is not coming

Answer (score 0):

For now try this solution, it works but, I don't like Ext id based element querying:-

```
var drawComponent = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Component', {
viewBox: false,
items: [{
    type: 'circle',
    fill: '#79BB3F',
    id: 'green-rect',
    itemId:'green-rect',
    radius: 100,
    x: 100,
    y: 100
}],
listeners: {
    'afterrender': function(panel) {
        alert("Hi");
        alert(panel.param);
        alert(panel);
        var itemArray = panel.items;
        //debugger;
        Ext.getElementById('green-rect').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

});

```
Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
width: 215,
height: 235,
layout: 'fit',
items: [drawComponent]
```

}).show();

Tried other solution posted but it doesn't work because even afterrender the child items are not Ext Component, but just a config.

There is no hide or addClass or any other Ext.Component method in the items object.

[image]

Comment: This view is being called by several other views.So, quering by Id will give duplicate id error

Answer (score 0):

You may do following:

```
if (var obj = itemArray.find('itemId', 'green-rect')) {
    obj.addCls('x-hide-display'); 
}
```

EDIT:

There is no `addCls` method for this object. You should use `hide()` method to hide rectangle:

```
if (var obj = itemArray.find('itemId', 'green-rect')) {
    obj.hide(); 
}
```

Comment: Nope !! It says undefined is not a function

Comment: Yes, I looked at docs - there is no method `addCls` for this object. What about to use `.hide()` method instead?

Comment: javascript gives error in itemArray.find('itemId','green-rect') saying undefined is not a function

Comment: What if you try:

`itemArray.get(1).hide()`